# SharePoint Addin: Retrieve list items error - collListItem of undefined

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, jsom

Can someone explain the use of:

```
this.collListItem
```

In this example:
[image]

When I try use this example I get the following error:
[image]

I am able to get around this by explicity creating the variable:

```
var collListItem = whatever...
```

But the former appears to work for Microsoft. Can someone explain how this works if they aren't creating the variable?

Comment: I do not think that sample works for anyone, ms included. Those errors has been in it for a long time

Comment: So what's the workaround then? If I wish to keep it as this.collListItem where should I instantiate the variable?

Comment: Yep, ran into the same issue with that code. Just remove 'this'

Comment: The problem with `this` is that it is function scoped, so it is a completely new `this` in the success method, so either save the `this` from the first method in a new variable (e.g `var _self = this`) and then use `_self` in the success method, or just use the workaround you already have found